# PowerBI Error : Details: "PostgreSQL: 28001: Cannot connect to the server company.onmicrosoft.com"

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I was working on a PowerBI report which I initially connected with the PostgreSQL on the Azure Cloud.
I was able to import the data and work on it till recently. I had whitelisted my earlier IP and hence connection was smooth. Today When I tried to connect from new IP (I have whitelisted this New IP as well) but it is not working. I am getting the following error. Not sure what should be done to continue working with the same report.
 `Details: "PostgreSQL: 28001: Cannot connect to the server company.onmicrosoft.com"`

When I go to edit settings I am not able to change anything there as well. Not sure what should be done. Can Anybody please help on this.

I tried the following but nothing worked

1. Searched for Answers on PowerBI Community
2. Searched for Answers on Stack over Flow
3. Tried to change Internet connection
4. Whitelisted all possible IP on Azure PostgreSQL
5. Restarted the server on Azure PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I finally figured out the solution to this problem so thought of posting it here so that it may help others who are stuck with similar problem

So this is what I did,

1. I checked the credentials it was all fine but I re-entered the server name and added `:5432` its Port number in front of the server name.
2. Then it again asked for username and password, that I provided and it got connected to the data source very well.

Finally after hours of trial and error the issue got resolved